# environment.production variable always true inside app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to set a config setting in my app.module file so that it's different depending on if I'm in production or not.

My `environment.ts` file has

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

My `environment.prod.ts` file has

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

In my `app.module.ts` file I am attempting something like this

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      level: (environment.production ? NgxLoggerLevel.OFF : NgxLoggerLevel.DEBUG)
    }),
...
```

When I do `console.log(environment.production)` anywhere it tells me this value is `false` as it should be while I am in the development environment.

My problem is that it seems to be acting as `true` in my app.module file. I'm trying to set my log statements to be disabled on the production environment in this case, but they are also getting disabled in development and production. (If I flip my conditional statement then they get enabled in both dev and production). So it's as if it's reading environment.production to be true when it shouldn't be.

Can the environment.production variable not be used like this in app.module or am I missing something else here?

Comment: could you add the `environment.dev.ts` to the question description?

Comment: `environment.ts` is the one I'm referring to as the dev one

Comment: Which version of `environment` are you importing into your app's module by default?

Comment: `environment.ts` is the default one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was directly importing the production version directly at the top of app.module.ts

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';
```

instead of

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```